# Implictly casting a dynamic object at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

Say I have the following code:

```
class MyField : DynamicObject 
{
     public dynamic Value { get; private set; }

     public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
     {
         result = binder.Type == Value.GetType() ? Value : null;
         return result != null;
     }

     public MyField(dynamic v) 
     {
          Value = v;
     }
}
// ...
public static class Program
{
    static void doSomething(ulong address) { /* ... */ }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
         dynamic field = new MyField((ulong)12345);
         doSomething(field); // fails as field is not a ulong.
         doSomething((ulong)field); // succeeds as field can be casted to a ulong.
         ulong field2 = field; // also succeeds
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the first call to `doSomething` to succeed? I'm writing a library to read a particular file format which uses serialized C-style structures; reading the file entails reading these saved structure definitions and then "populating" them with the data contained in the rest of the file. I have a "structure" `DynamicObject` class (to support dot-notation access) and a "field" `DynamicObject` class, which is primarily necessary to hold additional information on the contents of the field; although I could probably get rid of it, it would make certain other operations more difficult. What I'd like to do is just "pretend" `MyField` is a certain type (well, technically just any built-in primitive or array of primitives, including 2D arrays) and implicitly convert it to that type. However, the runtime fails to try to implicitly convert `field` to the type required by the underlying method signature if `field` doesn't match the type required.

Comment: @Greg Just easier use, I guess. I have a working implementation, but it uses a syntax like `field["sub1.sub2"].Value`, and I thought it would be more useful and readable to just be able to write `field.sub1.sub2`. I don't want to have to add casts to all my method calls, though.

Comment: Couldn't you use *Generic's*, `<T>` which would allow you to specify the type to a class at will, based on your needs?

Answer (score 1):

In the vein of Greg's answer, I came up with a solution that makes the runtime happy. It's not exactly what I was originally looking for, but it seems like the best solution.

Since I already have a large `if-else` tree in my source wherein I take an array of bytes and interpret them as an actual value-type, and indeed my current source does use an underlying generic `MyField<T>`, so this works fine. I can't recall why I wanted `MyField` to be `dynamic` in the first place.

Anyway, this is a modified solution.

```
class MyField<T>
{
    public dynamic Value { get; private set; }

    public MyField(dynamic v) { Value = v; }

    public static implicit operator T(MyField field)
    {
        return (T)field.Value;
    }
}
```

I keep coming back to wanting the runtime to just figure out what it needs to cast `MyField` to at runtime but I guess it's not that big of a deal. If anyone comes up with something better, let me know. I'm going to keep this question open in the meantime.

Comment: Glad my approach helped, sorry I didn't understand you too much.

Answer (score 0):

You potentially might want to look into *Generics*.  Coupled with an `interface` may make the dynamic usage far more viable.

```
public interface Helper <TInput, TOutput>
{
     <TOutput> DoSomething(TInput input);
}
```

So when you use this `interface` with a class, you'll implement your *type* for both input and output.  Which will give you quite a bit of flexibility, which should avoid those `cast` that you mentioned earlier.  A small example, I mean you could obviously adjust it based on needs but I still don't understand what you're trying to really do.

Comment: I have a previous implementation that does use generics and interfaces, but the generic `IField<T>` inherits from a non-generic `IField` which has a dynamic `Value` field; the only thing the generic adds is it specifies the type of `Value`. That being said, there is a solution using generics that does resolve this problem; I'll post an answer with a little more clarification.

Comment: Actually, with a little more experimentation this isn't quite what I wanted. The idea of inheriting from `DynamicObject` and overriding `TryConvert` is so that I don't have to specify what type `MyField` will be; the runtime should implicitly invoke `TryConvert` when I try to use `MyField` as its underlying type. The problem can be solved by making `MyField` a generic and adding an implicit cast operator to type `T`, but this isn't really what I wanted because I have to specify what type `MyField` is at instantiation when this information is really implied by the backing value of the field.

Comment: Sounds incredibly complex, a more concise question may attain better answers.

Comment: Basically, all I want to do is when I call a method using `field` as a parameter, if it doesn't accept an argument of type `MyField` as that parameter I want it to try again with `field.Value` as that parameter, instead of `field`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that I want `MyField` to behave like one of the built-in primitives; it has some underlying value (like `0`) but it also has other methods (like `TryParse`).